# Fuseki Server v1.1.1 : SPARQLer : SPARQL query Get Results in xml-to-html-links : the links gives Error 400

Tags: jena, fuseki, tdb

I am using Jena-Fuseki Server version 1.1.1. I am able to connect to my TDB and query it successfully via ControlPanel>Select Dataset>SPARQL Query.

But when the query is made with the **Get Results** where *Output = XML* and *If XML output, add XSLT style sheet (blank for none): xml-to-html-links*

The results are returned successfully, but the Links dont work as it should, instead leads to an Error as Follows:

```
Error 400: Parse error: 
SELECT (<http://www.myNamespace.org/owls/myOwl.owl

Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 9.
```

Each link in the result fires a SPARQL query as follows (which I recovered from the GET request URL):

```
SELECT (<http://www.myNamespace.org/owls/myOwl.owl#resource1> AS ?subject) ?predicate ?object {<http://www.myNamespace.org/owls/myOwl.owl#resource1> ?predicate ?object }
```

Encoded the Query using an Online URL Encoder/Decoder and pasted back as the query parameter in the GET request, and then things worked out to be as expected.

Is this a Bug in jena-fuseki v 1.1.1 or something is going wrong at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the "#" for the fragment is not escaped and is the SPARQL comment character.

The stylesheet needs to be XSLT 1.0.  I've put in some code to escape # as %23 though the XSLT 1.0 dance for this is not pretty.   There should be a new development build tonight else grab the updated xml-to-html-links.xsl from the GIT repo.

By the way - Fuseki2 has a completely different interface (javascript etc etc).  You may find that useful.